# Is there a scenario, where even BYE from UA on the dialog does not result in deletion of the dialog?

Tags: sip

Is there a scenario, where even BYE from UA on the dialog does not result in deletion of the dialog?
If so, can you please give an example for such scenario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use RFC3265 the reception of a BYE for a call having pending subscriptions will not terminate the dialog. See RFC 3265 Section 3.3.4. Dialog creation and termination

Answer (score 0):

If a UA doesn't receive the BYE, then of course it cannot know that the remote party has gone.

In that case, there are a few ways for it to realise that the dialog has in fact been terminated: it can use session timers, or watch what happens on the media plane - did those TCP connections terminate? have the RTCP reports stopped arriving? - or other mechanisms.

But otherwise, for the UA *sending* the BYE, the dialog has immediately terminated.